# Swift 3 - superclass method is executing instead of its override counterpart

Tags: objective-c, swift, inheritance, methods, overriding

How can I override the ObjC methods, `runThisMethod` and `controller:didChangeObject:`, from the `ViewControllerA` class so that the app executes the counterparts from the Swift subclass, `ViewControllerC`, instead?  In the code below, `[ViewControllerA runThisMethod(someParameter)]` will execute when the app detects a change in fetchedResultsController (via `[ViewControllerA controller:didChangeObject:]`.  Can somebody help me see what I'm missing?

**Main.swift**

```
let vc = ViewControllerC.init()
self.myNavigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

**ViewControllerA.h**

```
@interface ViewControllerA : UIViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
    - (void)setUpFetchedResultsController;
    - (void)runThisMethod:(SomeParameterClass *)someParameter;
@end
```

**ViewControllerA.m**

```
@implementation ViewControllerA
    - (void)setUpFetchedResultsController
    {
        // build fetch "request" here
        self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:[[MYCoreDataManager sharedCoreDataManager] managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
        self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    }

    - (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)someParameter atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
    {
        [self runThisMethod:someParameter]
    }

    - (void)runThisMethod:(SomeParameterClass *)someParameter
    {
        NSLog(@"This method will execute")
    }
@end
```

**ViewControllerB.h**

```
@interface ViewControllerB : ViewControllerA
    // declare a bunch of properties
@end
```

**ViewControllerB.m**

```
@implementation ViewControllerB

    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [self setUpFetchedResultsController];
    }

@end
```

**ViewControllerC.swift**

```
class ViewControllerC: ViewControllerB {

    override func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange someParameter: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
        // this function won't run
        self.runThisMethod(someParameter)
    }

    override func runThisMethod(someParameter){
        // this function won't run
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with a ```@objc``` tag for ```runThisMethod()```?

Comment: Just tried that and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was in the predicate of my `fetchedResultsController` property.  The predicate had a parameter that will causing `fetchResultsController` to always be nil when performing the fetch.  Thus, the delegate method, `controller:didChangeObject:` was not being triggered.

Answer (score 1):

When I set up a sample project with the code as you've mentioned (and set up a bridging header file which imports in ViewControllerB.h) the overridden runThisMethod on ViewControllerC executes correctly. This is with Xcode 8.2.1. So everything appears to work as it should with the set up you mention.

Could you perhaps upload a sample project showing the behaviour that you mention so that we can take a look? My suspicion is that something is not set up correctly somewhere ...

One thing you might not be doing (since you've only provided part of the code) is overriding NSFetchedResultsController's didChangeObject delegate method in ViewControllerC.

Comment: Thanks, Fahim. I just updated question with overriding didChangObject delegate method in ViewControllerC but it's still not executing `ViewControllerC.runThisMethod`. I actually didn't think I needed to override the didChangeObject delegate method since I'm not changing the code from ViewControllerA. Would you mind posting your code for ViewControllerC.swift?

Comment: Since it appears to be your code which has issues, it might be easier if you create a sample project to illustrate this issue and upload it somewhere. My ViewControllerC is bare-bones and has only the two methods you've posted above - or something similar to that.

Comment: Of course, if your code is *exactly* as it appears here, then you have an issue with the overridden version of runThisMethod in ViewControllerC since that does not take a parameter :) But I assume that that's just something you overlooked?

Comment: You're right, Fahim.  It does have a parameter... my careless mistake.  I've updated the question.  Re: sharing the code, I'm not going to be able to do that bc I'm not at liberty to my client's work and I don't have any basic apps that I could quickly modify.  I suspect that I'm not properly setting the `fetchResultsController` delegate property and/or I need to create another `fetchResultsController` for the subclass in order for the overriding `controller:didChangeObject` method to get triggered.  I'll try later and post results.

Comment: What I normally do in such situations (where I cannot share code) is to make a copy of the original project and pare everything down to the minimum necessary classes and code where it still shows the issue in action. Sometimes, just the task of paring things down shows where the issue is. If not, then you have a simple sample project that you can share with others. Maybe that will help?

Comment: I think posting code would have helped since I discovered that the problem was with my predicate.  Unfortunately, this beast of code was too much trouble to whittle down.  Thx for trying though!